# Auto select and retrieving checkbox values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I met some difficulties to code a function.
I generated some checkboxes in JavaScript.

I would like to auto select the element in the array `target[]` "March" and "September" and make them appear in the text area. So "March" and "September" appear checked and appear in the textarea.

But I also want to be able to edit the text area by selecting some other options. So if I check "January" and didn't touch to "March" and "September" they appear checked and aprear in the text area.

I really need it in JavaScript with no jQuery.

```js
//array of options
var array = new Array();
array[0] = "January";
array[1] = "February";
array[2] = "March";
array[3] = "April";
array[4] = "May";
array[5] = "Juny";
array[6] = "July";
array[7] = "August";
array[8] = "September";
array[9] = "October";
array[10] = "November";
array[11] = "December";

// values to of checkboxes I want to auto-check
var target = new Array();
target[0] = "March";
target[1] = "September";


var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in array) {
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  j = i.toString();

  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  cap = array[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#data {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.multiselect {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 50px;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="c_b">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<textarea id="t"></textarea> March and September have to be automatically checked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto select could be achieved in many ways, like using el.click(). Then you need to loop & see if el is 'checked - I've provided both basic example described in your question & more usable example with .checked.

```js
//array of options
var array = new Array();
array[0]="January";
array[1]="February";
array[2]="March";
array[3]="April";
array[4]="May";
array[5]="Juny";
array[6]="July";
array[7]="August";
array[8]="September";
array[9]="October";
array[10]="November";
array[11]="December";

// values to of checkboxes I want to auto-check
var target = new Array();
target[0]="March";
target[1]="September";


var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
 j = i.toString();

 val = j;
 //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
 var cb = document.createElement('input');
 var label= document.createElement("label");

 cap = array[i];
 var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
 cb.type = 'checkbox';
 cbh.appendChild(cb);
 cb.name = cap;
 cb.value = val;
 label.appendChild(cb); 
 label.appendChild(text);
 cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    if (e.target.value) t.value += e.target.name
  })
  //alternate version:
  //cb.addEventListener('click',updateText)
}

//function updateText(){
//  t.value = [null,...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s,el)=>el&&el.checked?s=(s||'')+el.name:s||'')
//}

document.querySelector('[name="March"]').click()
document.querySelector('[name="September"]').click()
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
    padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
}
.multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:50px;
}
.checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
      
label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

<textarea id="t"></textarea>

March and September have to be automitacly checked
```

Explanation of

```
[null,...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s,el)=>el&&el.checked?s=(s||'')+el.name:s||'')
```

First, we're taking all checkboxes within id with "**querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')**"

Next, prepend "**...**" to treat Node list as Array while forming new array with **[ ]** (also, adding "null" at index 0 for easier code later)

Then, **.reduce( )** to output string, looping each element of array, providing 2 arguments - **s** - same variable, passed between elements, adding strings to it, and **el** - each element from array (inpyt checkbox element).

It's es6, so arguments for reduce callback comes before "**=>**", ald after "=>" there's auto-returned expression.

Inside this expression, there's "if" shorthand - if el is **.checked** we're adding **el.name** to "s" (or empty string if we're just beginning), and if el isn't checked - we're just passing "s"(or empty string) further down the loop

Example based on watching target[] changes:

```js
//array of options
var array = new Array();
array[0]="January";
array[1]="February";
array[2]="March";
array[3]="April";
array[4]="May";
array[5]="Juny";
array[6]="July";
array[7]="August";
array[8]="September";
array[9]="October";
array[10]="November";
array[11]="December";

var arrayChangeHandler = {
  get: function(target, property) {
    return target[property];
  },
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    target[property] = value;
    array.forEach(n=>(target.includes(n) != document.querySelector('[name="'+n+'"]').checked) ? document.querySelector('[name="'+n+'"]').click() : null)
    return true;
  }
};

var target = new Proxy([], arrayChangeHandler);



var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
 j = i.toString();

 val = j;
 //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
 var cb = document.createElement('input');
 var label= document.createElement("label");

 cap = array[i];
 var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
 cb.type = 'checkbox';
 cbh.appendChild(cb);
 cb.name = cap;
 cb.value = val;
 label.appendChild(cb); 
 label.appendChild(text);
 cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click',updateText)
}

function updateText(){
  t.value = [null,...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s,el)=>el&&el.checked?s=(s||'')+el.name:s||'')
}

//document.querySelector('[name="March"]').click()
//document.querySelector('[name="September"]').click()
target[0]="March";
target[1]="September";
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
    padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
}
.multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:50px;
}
.checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
      
label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

<textarea id="t"></textarea>

March and September have to be automitacly checked
```

This example uses kinda new technogy - proxy, so it might not be 100% reliable, and won't work in older browsers, but i guess it's best bet without reactive framework.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I got a problem with your code. If you click 5 times on the same options, the text area will make appear 5 time the same one.

Comment: Yup, so uncomment commented code & comment first "cb.addEventListener('click',e=>{...." and it'll refresh textarea after each click, preventing duplicates

Comment: Waow, thank you very much ! Is it possible for ou to explain or edit your post with comments to explain your function updateText() ? I don't clearly understand all you did. It would also helpful for the one after me who will see the answer. TY

Comment: Sure, hope it's explained now :)

Comment: Thank you. I realized that you write the values ​​to be automatically selected (March and April). I would like that if I change the values ​​of the table, the values ​​of the table target [], the values ​​are automatically selected. It will be perfect.

Comment: That's not a trivial task, you'll need to call some update function directly or use reactive framework.

Comment: Because This is the principal part of the question. How do I use the array target[] to automaticly select the concerned checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, so I've added another snippet in the answer.

Comment: Yes, the proxy is not working for me. I need tu use Array. In my code (the one I will use) I retrieve a text field and create an array. This array from the text field is target[] in the snippet. So need to don't use proxy. Maybe a forEach() function will be able to do the same, but I didn't succeed to integrate it with your code.

Comment: I got a problem with the function updateText(), I would like a compatibility on Internet Explorer but IE send me an error, it seems to be the "..." and then the "=>" is providing an error too. If you have an idea how to correct it, I would be very thnakful !

Comment: If you need to support obsolete browsers, use [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=%3E%201%25&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20updateText()%7B%0D%0A%20%20t.value%20%3D%20%5Bnull%2C...document.querySelectorAll('%23checkboxes%20%5Btype%3D%22checkbox%22%5D')%5D.reduce((s%2Cel)%3D%3Eel%26%26el.checked%3Fs%3D(s%7C%7C'')%2Bel.name%3As%7C%7C'')%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

You can set checkbox to checked like this,

`cb.checked = true;`

When you iterate through the array check for your desired values and set checked to true.

Comment: I know but I would like to retrieve from the array target[] the values of array[] and make them appear in the text area. So when I click, the texte area display the value of the checkbox selected. But also the options automaticly selected by the array target[]